# How do I check whether data exist in list or not, my list has multiple data types contets?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to check whether user entered data already exist in my list or not, problem here i'm facing is I've a list with multiple data types.

So even if user enter a number which is a integer, it is taking as a string & even though that number is in the list, **code shows not in the list**.

If I declare user input as 'int' then user can not enter string data. I want to take user input from same code but with multiple datatypes.

If I use single data type either integer or String then code is working fine. But I'm facing problem with multiple data types.

```
my_list = ("a", "b", "c",4,5,6)

x= (input("Enter data : "))
if x in my_list:   
    print('Yes, in the list')
else:
    print('No, not in the list')
```

User should be able enter the data irrespective of data type, be it a integer or string & code should check that data whether it's available in my_list or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the another solution for this. I can use `try` and `except` function.

```
my_list = ('a', 'b', 'c',4,5,6)
x= (input("Enter data : "))
try:
    val = int(x)
    if val in my_list:   
        print('Yes, in the list')
    else:
        print('No, not in the list')
except ValueError :
    if x in my_list:   
        print('Yes, in the list')
    else:
        print('No, not in the list')
```

Answer (score 2):

One option can be convert the elements of `my_list` to `str`.

```
my_list = ("a", "b", "c",4,5,6)
my_list = [str(s) for s in my_list]  # Here, converting all elements to str

x = (input("Enter data : "))

if x in my_list:
    print('Yes, in the list')
else:
    print('No, not in the list')
```